# Speeding up a code: memory versus speed

Tags: matlab, performance, memory-management

I have to create and store several matrices in MATLAB. If I choose to go for a multidimensional array then I have a memory problem. If I choose to go for a cell then the code is very slow. How can I improve both computational speed and memory usage?

Here a simplified version of my code

```
%%%%% MAIN FILE %%%%%%
rng default;  %for reproducibility

%% Paramaters
N=20; 
M=400;
R=M/2; 
B=M/2;

%% Generate the matrix data of dimension NM x(1+1+N +(N-1)+(N-1))
data=[kron((1:1:M)', ones(N,1)) repmat((1:1:N)', M,1) randn(M*N, N +(N-1)+(N-1))]; 

%% Generate the matrix unob of dimension NMx(1+1+N-1)xR
unob=[repmat(data(:,1:2),1,1,R)  randn(M*N,N-1,R)]; 

%% Option 1: MEMORY PROBLEM
%bootdata1 and bootunob1 have respectively dimension NMx(1+1+N +(N-1)+(N-1))xB and NMx(1+1+N-1)xRxB
[bootdata1, bootunob1]=boot1(N,M,B,R,data, unob);

%% Option 2: SLOW, NEVER ENDING
%bootdata is a matrix of dimension NMx(1+1+N +(N-1)+(N-1))xB
%bootunob is a cell of dimension Bx1 with bootunob{b} that is a matrix of dimension NMx(1+1+N-1)
[bootdata, bootunob]=boot(N,M,B,R,data, unob) ;
```

function `boot1`

```
function [bootdata, bootunob]=boot1(N,M,B,R,data, unob)    

         %Allocate space
         bootdata=zeros(N*M,1+1+N+(N-1)+(N-1), B);
         bootunob=zeros(N*M,(1+1+N-1),R,B); 

         for b=1:B   

             %Draw uniformly at random with replacement M integers from {1,...,M} and 
             %store them into the vector networkindices of dimension 1xM
             networkindices =randi([1 M],M,1); 

             %Fill bootdata(:,:,b) and bootunob(:,:,:,b)
             for m=1:M
                 bootdata((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :,b)=data(data(:,1)==networkindices(m),:);
                 bootdata((m-1)*N+1:m*N,1,b)=m*(ones(N,1)); %change indices

                 for r=1:R
                     bootunob((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :,r,b)=unob(unob(:,1,r)==networkindices(m),:,r); 
                     bootunob((m-1)*N+1:m*N,1,r,b)=m*(ones(N,1));
                 end
             end


         end
end
```

Function `boot`:

```
function [bootdata, bootunob]=boot(N,M,B,R,data, unob)    

         %Allocate space
         bootdata=zeros(N*M,1+1+N+(N-1)+(N-1), B);
         bootunob=cell(B,1);

         for b=1:B
             bootunob{b}=zeros(N*M,(1+1+N-1),R) ;

             %Draw uniformly at random with replacement M integers from {1,...,M} and 
             %store them into the vector networkindices of dimension 1xM
             networkindices =randi([1 M],M,1); 

             %Fill bootdata(:,:,b) and bootunob{b}
             for m=1:M
                 bootdata((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :,b)=data(data(:,1)==networkindices(m),:);
                 bootdata((m-1)*N+1:m*N,1,b)=m*(ones(N,1)); %change indices

                 for r=1:R
                     bootunob{b}((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :,r)=unob(unob(:,1,r)==networkindices(m),:,r); 
                     bootunob{b}((m-1)*N+1:m*N,1,r)=m*(ones(N,1));
                 end
             end
         end

end
```

Comment: I have also tried with structures but it does not help, e.g. inside the called function use `for r=1:R
                     bootunob.b((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :,r)=unob(unob(:,1,r)==networkindices(m),:,r); 
                     bootunob.b((m-1)*N+1:m*N,1,r)=m*(ones(N,1));
                 end`

Comment: `R=M/2; B=M/2;` Shouldn't `R` be `N/2`?

Comment: @rahnema1 No, Why?

Comment: Two equal objects and different naming

Comment: I see, they are equal just in this example, but they could be different.

Comment: `bootunob` requires nearly 51.5 GB.A workaround is that you can run `boot1` 200 times and in each time you create `bootunob = zeros(N*M,(1+1+N-1),1,B)` and save the result to the disk as a mat file. So you will have 200 mat files each one include a matrix with 256 MB of size.

Comment: Is dynamically naming matrices in a loop the only way to proceed?

Comment: You can directly change a mat file please see [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html)

Comment: I don't quite understand how it works and what is the advantage. If you have time, could you write down an answer? Thanks

Comment: That is available since R2011b.

Comment: I have read about matfile but it seems to me that I have to firstly save the "big matrix" and then the function matfile allows me to load only sections of it. How can this help to overcome the memory issue?

Comment: So I work with Octave that doesn't have matfile implemented,However a well answer submitted by user9985.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW METHOD**

Significantly faster, the write speed is in the order of 100-300MB/s on my computer, although the bottleneck has become part of the code, see my comment at the end of this section.

The new `bootFaster` method:

```
function [bootDataFiles, bootUnobFiles] = bootFaster(N, M, B, R, data, unob)
    % Temporary Variables
    % Based on some simple math, these slices should be OKish. This will
    % crash and burn if you try to use the save with files greater than
    % 2^31 bytes, so just be careful with that.
    bootDataTemp = zeros(N*M, 1+1+N+(N-1)+(N-1), 1);
    bootUnobTemp = zeros(N*M, 1+1+(N-1), R, 1);

    % Matricies containing the file names for the .mat files. There are B
    % rows.
    bootDataFiles = zeros(B, 17);
    bootUnobFiles = zeros(B, 17);

    for b = 1:B
        networkIndices = randi([1 M], M, 1);

        for m = 1:M
            bootDataTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :) = data(data(:, 1) == networkIndices(m), :);
            bootDataTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, 1) = m * (ones(N, 1)); %change indices

            for r = 1:R
                bootUnobTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :, r) = unob(unob(:, 1, r) == networkIndices(m), :, r); 
                bootUnobTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, 1, r) = m * (ones(N, 1));
            end
        end

        % Creates the file name for the bth matrix.
        % NOTE: if you change the 5 it will change the length of each file
        % name, you will have to change the number of columns in
        % bootDataFiles and bootUnobFiles accordingly.
        bootDataFileB = sprintf('bootData%5.i.mat', b);
        bootUnobFileB = sprintf('bootUnob%5.i.mat', b);

        % Writes the contents of the tempoary variables to the file
        save(bootDataFileB, 'bootDataTemp', '-v6');
        save(bootUnobFileB, 'bootUnobTemp', '-v6');

        % Storing the file names.
        bootDataFiles(b, :) = bootDataFileB;
        bootUnobFiles(b, :) = bootUnobFileB;
    end

    % Convert the values back to chars (each row will not be a "string")
    bootDataFiles = char(bootDataFiles);
    bootUnobFiles = char(bootUnobFiles);
end
```

To use the data from this you can now take advantage of the matfile method as follows.

```
[bootDataFiles, bootUnobFiles] = bootFaster(N,M,B,R,data, unob);

bootDataAtbFile = matfile(bootDataFiles(b, :));
% Note the use of "bootDataTemp" to access the data, you have to use
% the name of the temporary variable that you stored the data in inside
% bootFaster. E.g. to access the bootUnob data you would have to use
% bootUnobTemp, or whatever you choose to rename them to.
bootDataAtb = bootDataAtbFile.bootDataTemp;
```

Final note. This line:

```
bootUnobTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :, r) = unob(unob(:, 1, r) == networkIndices(m), :, r);
```

Is extremely slow. For example. with N = 30 and M = 200. That line took up 2/3 of the execution time. Would **highly** recommend seeing if you can refactor this.

---

**OLD METHOD - Too slow in 2015b due to compression**

Using the `matfile` function and the ability to write to file this becomes pretty easy to implement. There is not much that you have to change about your code. See below for the code to get it to work.

In your MAIN FILE you need to do:

```
file = bootFast(N,M,B,R,data, unob);

bootdata1F = file.bootdata;
bootunob1F = file.bootunob;
```

and the `bootFast`:

```
function file = bootFast(N, M, B, R, data, unob)
% Opens the file, or creates it if it doesn't exsit
file = matfile('output', 'Writable', true);

% Sets the sizes of the variables
file.bootdata(N*M, 1+1+N+(N-1)+(N-1), B) = 0;
file.bootunob(N*M, 1+1+(N-1), R, B) = 0;

bootdataTemp = file.bootdata(:, :, 1);
bootunobTemp = file.bootunob(:, :, :, 1);

for b = 1:B
    networkindices = randi([1 M], M, 1);

    for m = 1:M
        bootdataTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :) = data(data(:, 1) == networkindices(m), :);
        bootdataTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, 1) = m * (ones(N, 1)); %change indices

        for r = 1:R
            bootunobTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, :, r) = unob(unob(:, 1, r) == networkindices(m), :, r); 
            bootunobTemp((m-1)*N+1:m*N, 1, r) = m * (ones(N, 1));
        end
    end
    file.bootdata(:, :, b) = bootdataTemp;
    file.bootunob(:, :, :, b) = bootunobTemp;
end
end
```

I have limited disk writes to occur only once per b in an attempt to speed that up, but you may have to play around with the exact location based on how much memory you have.

P.S. I hope you have a SSD.

Comment: For indexing, you can use just `:` instead of `1:end`

Comment: @SardarUsama True. I forgot to change to : when I brought the print statement out of the inner for loops. d'oh! Fixed

Comment: @user9985 Thanks. These lines `file.bootdata(:, :, b) = bootdataTemp;
    file.bootunob(:, :, :, b) = bootunobTemp;` take forever. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes. Those are the lines that write to file. I've actually been playing around with it to see if there is any way to get it to run faster by having B 2-D bootdata and B 3-D bootunob entries within file, rather than then 1 3D bootdata and 1 4-D bootunob entries.

Comment: @user3285148. One of the reasons that they are so slow is that matlab has compression on by default for writting to matfiles that are this large. What version of matlab do you use?

Comment: I am using R2015b

Comment: @user3285148. Yeah I have the same version. The problem is that you need to use version 7 or 7.3 of .mat files in order to save files of size greater than 2GB (which is definitely the case here) and both of those implement compression on by default. I think I have an idea for a janky workaround, will get back to you with it.

Comment: @user3285148. Give that one a try.